# possible logic error in textbook

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

In my textbook, the author claims the following: If $x$ is not a limit point of $(x_{n_k})$ [where $(x_{n_k})$ is subsequence of $(x_n)$] if 
$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \; \exists N > 0\; \; such \; that \; \;  n > N \implies\; \; |x-x_{n_k}| > \epsilon $$

I think this is incorrect and here is my reasoning: Since $x$ is not a limit point, then theres no subsquence of $x_{n_k}$ converging to $x$ so that $x_{n_k}$ itself does not converge to $x$. This means:

$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \; \; such\; that \; \; \forall N > 0 \; \; \exists n > 0 \; \; so \; \; n > N \implies |x_{n_k} - x | \geq \epsilon $$

Now, what is going on here?

Comment: The statement in the books is correct.

Comment: Can you give a reason why? Because I am not seeing it

Comment: as @Kavi said the statement is correct. Note that $x$ is a limit point of a sequence $(x_k)$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there are infinitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|x-x_n|<\epsilon$

Comment: There is some ttruth contained in what younare thinking, although the book’s statement is true, which is this:  by choosing epsilon even smaller, you can keep the entire subsequence outside the ball around $x$, which follows from the books version by just picking the closest of the finitely many points inside the book’s epsilon, and making yours smaller it’s distance to $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument **does not** say that $x$ is not a limit point of $(x_{n_k})$.

As Masacroso points out in his comment, $x$ is a limit point of a sequence $(\xi_k)$ if and only if for every $ϵ>0$ there are infinitely many $k∈\mathbb N$ such that $|x−\xi_k|<ϵ$.

Take $\xi_k = x_{n_k}$. Then negation leads to:

$x$ is not a limit point of $(x_{n_k})$ if and only if there exists $ϵ>0$ such that there are only finitely many $k∈\mathbb N$ such that $|x−x_{n_k}|<ϵ$. The latter means
$$ \exists \epsilon > 0 \; \; \exists K > 0\; \text{such that }  \forall k > K : |x-x_{n_k}| \ge \epsilon $$
This is of course equivalent to
$$ \exists \epsilon' > 0 \; \; \exists K > 0\; \text{such that }  \forall k > K : |x-x_{n_k}| > \epsilon' $$
In fact, given $\epsilon$, take $\epsilon' = \epsilon/2$. Conversely, given $\epsilon'$, then $\epsilon = \epsilon'$ will do.

You correctly state that since $x$ is not a limit point, then there is no subsquence of $x_{n_k}$ converging to $x$ so that $x_{n_k}$ itself does not converge to $x$. However, this is **not equivalent** to the original statement. It is possible that $x_{n_k}$ does not converge to $x$, but nevertheless has $x$ as a limit point. Therefore your formula is correct, but is not the **adequate property**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is not  a limit points of $(x_{n_k})$ then there is an interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ which contains at most finitely many points of the sequence (and conversely). This means $|x_{n_k}-x | \geq \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This is exactly what the book is saying.

Comment: Meaning that infinitely many of the terms of the sequence lie outside the ball. But how is my interpretation different? What is the error in my reasoning? If x is not limit point, doesnt it mean that the sequence doesnt converge to x and so my interpretion is also correct

Comment: It implies that the sequence does not converge to $x$ but it implies more. Not converging to $x$ is not **equivalent** to not being  a limit point. @James